# How can I pull data from a webpage and store it google sheets? Trending data from enviormental monitor

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, iot

I have this environmental monitor from a company that went out of business but it's useful, it has an NDIR co2 sensor, tempature and RH. It has an ethernet port and webserver.

You can go to different urls such as **127.0.0.1/setget?%sen-3**
and it outputs:

```
handler.setget(%sen-3)
500
```

where 500 would be the current room co2 concentration in ppm. Can someone point me in the direction to go about scraping this into a database and charting it to see trends in co2. Ex: how much does co2 rise while sleeping, how much does it change with occupancy, etc. I was thinking Google Sheets and Google Charts would be a good start. How can I scrape this page and store it in Google Sheets? Python? I only have experience with HTML, PHP but don't mind learning python if it isn't too complicated of a project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

got a lead! Need to setup a rasberry pi with home assistant. then use sensor scrape to scarpe the data and define it as a sensor. Home assistant is a power interface!

https://www.home-assistant.io/components/sensor.scrape/